# How to access package using access type?

Tags: package, ada

Lets say i have two procedure in package pack.ads now i want to access pack package using acess type?
below is my spec file

pack.ads

```
 package pack is
  procedure pac1;
  procedure pac2;
 end pack;
```

note-i have skip package body.
Now i want to access these package using access type.below is my attemp which is bad ..please help me to fix it

main.adb

```
  with pack 
  procedure main is
  type my_access is access all pack;--
```

ths is bad attemp but please can any one help with it?

Comment: What is the [actual problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/163188) that you are trying to solve?

Comment: @trashgod i m trying to access package using access type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a serious (but occasionally encountered) misunderstanding of what a package is in Ada.

A package is much like a namespace in C++, or perhaps simply a file in C. You can't have a pointer to either of these things.

You can have a pointer/access type that refer to objects/subprograms/tasks.